# MAX of SUM using nested aggregations queries

Tags: sql-server, subquery, aggregate-functions

I've started to learn SQL 2 months ago in the context of a DataScience MSccursur I'm following.

Using SQL SERVER and the sample database WideWorldImporters, I have to build a query to select, for each customer category, the one who has generated the maximum losses related to orders not converted in invoices.

The result I must obtain is the following table:

[image]

I built the following query:

```
SELECT  CustomerCategoryName,
    MAX(SumLossesOrdersNotConverted) As MaxLoss
FROM
(   SELECT  Cat.CustomerCategoryName,
    SUM(OL.Quantity * OL.UnitPrice) as SumLossesOrdersNotConverted,
    C.CustomerName AS CustName,
    C.CustomerID AS CustID
    FROM    Sales.OrderLines AS OL 
        JOIN Sales.Orders O ON OL.OrderID = O.OrderID
        JOIN Sales.Customers AS C ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
        JOIN Sales.CustomerCategories AS Cat ON Cat.CustomerCategoryID = C.CustomerCategoryID
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM Sales.Invoices as I
            WHERE O.OrderID = I.OrderID
        )
    GROUP BY C.CustomerID,C.CustomerName,Cat.CustomerCategoryName
) AS LossSummary
GROUP BY CustomerCategoryName
ORDER BY MAX(SumLossesOrdersNotConverted) DESC
```

And was able to get the 2 first columns:

[image]

But despite a lot a search and efforts, I'm still not able to add the corresponding CustomerName and CustomerID colums.

Of course, I've tried to add CustName, CustId in my outer select. But it does'nt give me expecetd results as I must add CustName, CustId in the GROUP BY:

[image]

I need a table with maxloss per category and the corresponding customerid

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks by advance.

Comment: what issue you are getting. Select CustomerCategoryName,
    MAX(SumLossesOrdersNotConverted) As MaxLoss, CustName, CustId

Comment: on top of what @DeepakKumar said, you also need to add `CustName`, `CustId` columns to the outer `group by`

Comment: Create Sql fiddle. Then I will check

Comment: I've already done that, of course, and it does'nt give me expecetd result: as I mus add CustName, CustId in the GROUP BY , i get following result:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
WITH
    LossSummary AS (
        SELECT  Cat.CustomerCategoryName,
                SUM(OL.Quantity * OL.UnitPrice) as SumLossesOrdersNotConverted,
                C.CustomerName AS CustName,
                C.CustomerID AS CustID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cat.CustomerCategoryName ORDER BY SUM(OL.Quantity * OL.UnitPrice) DESC) AS [Order]
        FROM    Sales.OrderLines AS OL 
        JOIN    Sales.Orders O ON OL.OrderID = O.OrderID
        JOIN    Sales.Customers AS C ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
        JOIN    Sales.CustomerCategories AS Cat ON Cat.CustomerCategoryID = C.CustomerCategoryID
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM Sales.Invoices as I
                    WHERE O.OrderID = I.OrderID
                )
        GROUP BY C.CustomerID,C.CustomerName,Cat.CustomerCategoryName
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    LossSummary
WHERE   [Order] = 1
;
```

Comment: I found a ) missing on line 7 before the AS and after adding it yes, it's working ! 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked!  Thanks for the note, @max.  I've edited the answer.  If you wouldn't mind, and if you can, an upvote on the answer would give me some reputation points (which I crave).